# Getting Error: property of 'undefined' in Nested React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get data through nested react-router but getting the value undefined.

My data:

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Skateboard1",
        price: 20.10,
        img: picture1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Skateboard2",
        price: 80.50,
        img: picture2
    }
]
```

App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
 
        <Route exact path="/shop/:id" render={(itemProp) => <ShopItem shopItemId={itemProp.match.params.id} />} />

      </Switch> 
    </Router>
    
  );
}
```

ShopItem Component:

```
const ShopItem = (shopItemId) => {

        const item = data.find((i) => i.id === shopItemId) 
    
    return(
        <div>
               <h2>{item.name}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

on `console.log(shopItemId)`

```
{
  shopItemId: "1"
}
```

It seems like a silly mistake. But can't get what's wrong.

Please any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `data.find((i) => i.id === shopItemId)` didn't find any element that matches the comparison, so `item` is undefined. `shopItemId` is an object, so the real value is `shopItemId.shopItemId` and use `==` operator since one value is an `integer` and the other is a `string` like:

```
const item = data.find((i) => i.id == shopItemId.shopItemId)
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's returning undefined, not sure why. Above I have posted the content of the data as well.

Comment: Is there anything else would you like to see besides the content of the data?

Comment: `data`  looks good, maybe `shopItemId` has a different value, or it's a `string` and it's expecting an `int`.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the value of `shopItemId`. Could you look it again, please?

Comment: right, the problem is that `shopItemId` is a `string` and the `id` of the `data` element is an `integer`, `===` operation first checks the types of the values, so `1` is not equal to `"1"`. u can use `==` instead of `===` like `data.find((i) => i.id == shopItemId)`

Comment: I did that but still getting the same error

Comment: I tried `const a = parseInt(shopItemId,10)` but it didn't work either.

Comment: ohh, based on the `console.log(shopItemId)` i can see that it's an object, the actual value that u want is `shopItemId.shopItemId`

Comment: You can update your answer if you like to